# UTC TimeZone in Europe gives year 2014 instead of 2013

Tags: iphone, ios, timezone, utc

I´m using "UTC" to set the timeZone.

If the "System Settings->General->Region Format" is on USA, the date is 2013. 
If it is on Europe the date is 2014. I´m using the code below

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *dataTmp = [formatter dateFromString:[[[self.commManager.bolsaDic objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"TradeTimeUtc"]];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YY HH:mm"];       
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

Anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never ever use YYYY in your date formatting or parsing. It's an ISO year and it will screw up whatever it touches. Ask Apple - this is what caused the DND bug in iOS on Jan 1.

Always use yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has something to do with the 'YY' in your date format. Try changing it to lowercase 'yy'. (Don't ask me why!)

EDIT: Ah, apparently uppercase Y returns the year the current week started in, so if it was 1st January 2014 but a Wednesday, the week started in 2013.

Comment: Not sure why it differs for different regions... maybe the day the week starts on varies